# How to direct events on overlapped views on iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiscrollview, uicollectionview

Recently I encountered a tricky case. I have a view hierarchy like this:

UIView (0, 0, 500, 300)

+-- UIScrollView (0, 0, 500, 300)

+-- UICollectionView (0, 0, 500, 300)

In this hierarchy, I have UIScrollview and the UICollectionView added on UIView in the same frame. So The UICollectionView is right on top of the UIScrollView.

The features I would like to achieve are:

1. Swiping with one finger will be affecting the UICollectionView
2. The Pan Gesture and the Pinch Gesture with two fingers will be scrolling and zooming the UIScrollView.

Please let me know what would be the best way to achieve this.

Thanks!

Comment: Is the collection view a subview of the scroll view?  If not, why do you think it's a good design for gestures to manipulate a non-visible view?

Comment: Thanks @Avi, I could make this change. If that is the case, not sure if I could make the case simpler

Answer (score 0):

Try to use method of controller `touchesDidMoved`. With it you can detect how many touches you get and as well set content offset to your `UIScrollView` or `UICollectionView`.

Still do not know if that is the best approach, mb there is better one.